# Get the full list of feed url patterns?

Tags: iphone, feed

I have seen some similar questions on stackoverflow and on searched on google too but could not get a satisfying answer.

I am doing an application in which data is shown into a table. Now on selecting a row I need to now that if this will lead to a page where I am expected to see feeds. I am trying to detect the url via this method, but not sure that this will give me the best results and may be I would be missing some more cases, so I need the help in two ways:

- Is there a better way to do this?
- Or are these cases complete (means, do I need to test more cases)?

  ```
  -(BOOL)checkForTheFeed:(NSString *)address{    
      if([address hasSuffix:@"/feed/"])
          return YES;
      if([address hasPrefix:@"feed://"])
          return YES;
      if([address rangeOfString:@"=rss"].location != NSNotFound)
          return YES;
      if([address rangeOfString:@".rss"].location != NSNotFound)
          return YES;
      if([address hasSuffix:@"/rss/"])
          return YES;
      if([address rangeOfString:@"/feeds."].location != NSNotFound)
          return YES;
      if([address rangeOfString:@".feeds."].location != NSNotFound)
          return YES;
      if([address hasSuffix:@".xml"])
          return YES;
      return NO;
  }
  ```

If I miss some cases please try to add them.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: Why not access the URLs and see if you get RSS data back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really look at the content-type and content of the remote resource. Looking at a URL to figure out what kind of data it points to is the wrong approach.